# Download a zip file from a URI with authentication and navigation through mutiple staging URLs

Tags: java, authentication, https, uri

with zero experience in writing code to access URLs, below is my attempt to solve my problem so please bear with me. 
To explain the scenario - I am trying to automate the process of downloading a zip file from the World Health Organization website. The path to this file is as follows:

1. One has to login through a microsoftonline login page
2. Post login you are taken to a user area page
3. From here I need to navigate to download area page where the file resides

Here's an attempt at the code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class WHODataDownload{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Install Authenticator
        MyAuthenticator.setPasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
        Authenticator.setDefault (new MyAuthenticator ());

        try {

            String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/whoumcprod.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=bb2a2e3a-c5e7-4f0a-88e0-8e01fd3fc1f4&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%2fwhoumcprod.onmicrosoft.com%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=id_token&scope=email+openid&response_mode=query&nonce=2rEvxJKKHe4qFrsr%2feJh4g%3d%3d&nux=1&nca=1&domain_hint=whoumcprod.onmicrosoft.com&mkt=en-US&lc=1033&state=StateProperties%3deyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6YWNjMzk4YzctZTdiNy00MTM0LWFjNDktMjgyZDg4NDJiOTc1IiwiVElEIjoiMWMwYTNjOTgtODY1Ny00YTEzLTlmMWMtNjMyYTE3MDc4YjJjIn0";

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

            System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);
            String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            // open the new connnection again
            URL newUrl = new URL ("https://www.who-umc.org/user-area/vigibase-extract-case-level/");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) newUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Chrome");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

            URL downloadUrl = new URL("https://downloadarea.who-umc.org/download/product?id=1254");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("download.zip");
            copy(in, out, 1024);
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
                byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
                int n = input.read(buf);
                while (n >= 0) {
                  output.write(buf, 0, n);
                  n = input.read(buf);
                }
                output.flush();
              }


            }
```

Here's the authenticator code:

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {  
    private static String username = "";
    private static String password = "";

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication (MyAuthenticator.username, 
                MyAuthenticator.password.toCharArray());
    }

    public static void setPasswordAuthentication(String username, String password) {
        MyAuthenticator.username = username;
        MyAuthenticator.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into browser automation, such as using Selenium and a suitable driver?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul No, I haven't. Do you think Selenium may be a better approach to this?

Comment: If this is something you run locally, yes, because it would move your problem out of the "what do I do with the raw HTML that I just downloaded" to "What's the XPath or CSS to locate the correct element on the page, which Selenium makes trivial to enter and submit. You'd be working with inputs and buttons instead of raw markup. This may help you get started: https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/getting-started-with-webdriver-selenium-for-java-in-eclipse

Comment: For something you incorporate into a portable piece of software or need to run server side, Selenium+WebDriver may be the wrong approach, because of the overheads of running as well as installing the relevant drivers in the first place, and which need to be matched to the Operating System.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul In that case, Selenium may not be a good fit as this process of downloading data is part of a larger automation effort. It's just the way this website is set up, we are having a hard time incorporating this piece with the rest of the project.

Comment: May I ask how you intend to deploy/run this? Maybe it's still worth the one-off effort in favour of a vastly simplified development and possible maintenance thereof.

Comment: A script on the Azure server that will get triggered through a chron job every 3 months to download data of that quarter.

Comment: Apparently you can run Selenium on a cloud service instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110879/download-a-zip-file-from-a-uri-with-authentication-and-navigation-through-mutipl?noredirect=1#comment98955469_56110879 - the code presented is in C#, but presumably would be similar in Java.

Comment: Another possibility might be to create a container (e.g. Docker) that contains all your dependencies, including the chosen browser and its driver, which you could then spin up each quarter to do the work?